# protractor debug cannot find module

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, protractor

I'm using protractor on my AngularJS/Rails project and when I start

```
webdriver-manager start
rails s -e test --port=4000 -P tmp/pids/protractor_test_server.pid
protractor debug --specs spec/javascripts/protractor_specs/users/create_user_spec.js.coffee spec/javascripts/protractor.conf.js
```

I get the following error:

```
_spec.js.coffee spec/javascripts/protractor.conf.js
util.puts: Use console.log instead
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on port 5858
< Debugger listening on port 5858
connecting to port 5858... ok
break in timers.js:94
< module.js:338
<     throw err;
<           ^
< Error: Cannot find module '/home/map7/myproject/localhost:5858'
<     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
<     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
<     at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:501:10)
<     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:133:15)
< Failed to open socket on port 5858, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
 92 }
 93 
>94 function listOnTimeout() {
 95   var msecs = this.msecs;
 96   var list = this;
debug> 
(^C again to quit)
debug> 
Error 0
```

If I run protractor without the debug then it runs my tests fine but I have no debugger. I currently have a problem where I need to use the debugger.

NOTE: I've tried with protractor 1.4.0 & 2.1.0